# pandas dataframe confusing difference between .count and .sum

Tags: python, pandas

In the dataframe below, adam was contacted twice by email and once by phone. If I use sum() to count total email usages, I get the correct result: 2.
But if I use count(), adam gets 3.
**Why does that happen? Does .count() not distinguish between True and False Booleans?**

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({'Name':['adam','ben','adam','adam','ben'], 'Type' ['Email', 'Phone', 'Email','Phone','Phone']}, index =[0,1,2,3,4])

df.groupby('Name')['Type'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(['Email']).sum())
df.groupby('Name')['Type'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(['Email']).count())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The technical definition of the [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) method is to count the non-missing values. Since all your values are non-missing it simply returns the number of rows for each group.

Comment: Thank you Ted. I saw on pydata.org that Count returns a Series with number of non-NA/null observations. I didn't know that that meant non-missing values. Thank you.